# How do I handle click of a button inside canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following WPF Code:

```
Grid Width="260" Height="170">
    <Border Margin="5" MouseEnter="UIElement_OnMouseEnter">
        <Border.Background>
            <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Canvas Background="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="True">
                      <Rectangle Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20" Width="200" Height="50" Fill="Tan"/>

                        <Button
        x:Name="ToggleButton"
        Width="30"
        Height="30"
        Canvas.Top="10" 
                            IsHitTestVisible="True"
                            PreviewMouseDown="ToggleButton_OnPreviewMouseDown"
        Canvas.Left="10"
        />

                    </Canvas>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="225"/>
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that the button cannot be clicked. Does anyone knows a solution/workaround for this problem ?  Also I tried with background transparent for canvas instead of null.

Thanks, 
Lucian

Comment: Try to add a `Click=""` attribute to your `<button>`-tag. Maybe you forgot it?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be clicked"? What does your `ToggleButton_OnPreviewMouseDown` method do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Button x:Name="ToggleButton" 
        Width="30" Height="30"
        Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10"
        IsHitTestVisible="True"
        PreviewMouseDown="ToggleButton_OnPreviewMouseDown"
        Click="ButtonToggleButton_Click"
        />
```

Note 'Click="ButtonToggleButton_Click"'

Your C# Code will be:

```
private void ButtonToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do Actions here
}
```

Edit: I just put this in VS and noticed what you mean by 'cannot be clicked' -- Your button is being drawn as apart of the VisualBrush method.

If you move your button declaration from outside of that ie.

```
 <Border Margin="5" MouseEnter="UIElement_OnMouseEnter">
      <Button
       x:Name="ToggleButton"
       Width="30" Height="30"
       IsHitTestVisible="True"
       Click="ButtonToggleButton_Click"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Margin="10,10,0,0"
    />
    <Border.Background>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas Background="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="True">
                  <Rectangle Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20" Width="200" Height="50" Fill="Tan"/>

                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Border.Background>
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="225"/>
    </Border.Effect>
</Border>
```

You will get a normally functioning button in the top left of your canvas, from there you can style button individually.

Comment: It was one of the first solution to try events like Click, PreviewMouseDown, MouseDown, etc.

Comment: @lusian_andrei Expanded the solution. Your button was being rendered as part of the VisualBrush section. The provided code will draw a normal button in the top left of your canvas.

Additionally, you shouldn't need a visual brush to do this, unless you've removed details this can be done by just styling the Canvas, Border and rectangle with properties.

Comment: Cool,never cross my mind and i still get the effect desired. http://i1055.photobucket.com/albums/s514/Panciu_Odobesti/Shadow_zpsyqeu68vi.png

Comment: @lusian_andrei Looks great, good luck with the rest! Don't forget to mark an accepted answer too.